# persistence in certain directory

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a web app in which there are four directories user, admin, superadmin. I am login user and directing each of them to these directories using sessions depending who the user is and it's working out well.

How can I ensure that the user session persists in the directory they are in until they log out. For instance, if I log in as admin, I would like all my sessions only to persist in the admin directory without going to another directory. I do not have and idea please help

This is path to the root folder: `F:\wamp\www\authentication\public\`

- admin : `F:\wamp\www\authentication\public\admin\`
- user : `F:\wamp\www\authentication\public\user`

I do not want to return to the root directory which contains this directories.. Kindly assist me and give me sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conflen=strlen('SCRIPT');
$B=substr(__FILE__,0,strrpos(__FILE__,'/'));
$A=substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], strrpos($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$C=substr($B,strlen($A));
$posconf=strlen($C)-$conflen-1;
$D=substr($C,1,$posconf);
$host='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$D;
$path=$host.dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
define('FRAMEWORK_PATH', $path.'/');
```

This is working but give more answers. i found it in php manual